# Remove all attributes in HTML tag except specified with regex

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to make regex which remove all attributes from HTML tags except specified ones.

I have this HTML code:

```
<p class="someClass" id="someId" style="border: 1px solid black" name="someName" foo="bar"></p>
```

And I want to remove all attributes except **class**, **id** and **name**, code should look like:

```
<p class="someClass" id="someId" name="someName">Text</p>
```

I have this regex:

```
<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\sid=['"][^'"]*['"]))?[^>]*?(\/?)>
```

and use pattern

```
<$1$2>
```

It only works for attribute *id*. How to do it for all specified attributes?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3cvun My example on regexr.com

Comment: So, this is JavaScript? Why not use a DOM parser?

Comment: I agree with WiktorStribiżew. As [pointed out many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4103025), regular expressions are just not a reliable way of parsing HTML.

Comment: I know DOM parser is better solution, but using regex is requirement for this project. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a negative lookahead, which will tell your expression to either 1. eat one character, or 2. match the special sequence, then rinse and repeat:

```
<(\w+)\s*(?:(?:(?:(?!class=|id=|name=)[^>]))*((?:class|id|name)=['"][^'"]*['"]\s*)?)+>
```

Explanation:

1. `<(\w+)\s*` *(match open of tag and tagname)*
2. `(?:` *(begin enclosure of main construct (note that it doesn't remember matches))*
3. `(?:(?:(?!class=|id=|name=)[^>]))*`   *(look ahead for no special token, then eat one character, repeat as many times possible, don't bother to remember anything)*
4. `((?:class|id|name)=['"][^'"]*['"])\s*?` *(lookahead failed, so special token ahead, let's eat it! note the regular, 'remembering' parens)*
5. `)+` *(end enclosure of main construct; repeat it, it'll match once for each special token)*
6. `>` *(end of tag)*

At [this point](https://regex101.com/r/yZ3tX5/2) you might have the matches you need, if your regex flavor supports multiple matches per group.  In .NET for example, you'd have something similar to this: $1 = 'a', $2[0]='class="someClass"', $2[1]='id="someId"', etc.

But if you find that only the last match is remembered, you may have to simply repeat the main construct for each token you want to match, like so: (matches will be $1-$4)

```
<(\w+)\s*(?:(?:(?:(?!class=|id=|name=)[^>]))*((?:class|id|name)=['"][^'"]*['"]\s*)?)(?:(?:(?:(?!class=|id=|name=)[^>]))*((?:class|id|name)=['"][^'"]*['"]\s*)?)(?:(?:(?:(?!class=|id=|name=)[^>]))*((?:class|id|name)=['"][^'"]*['"]\s*)?)[^>]*>
```

([see it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/yZ3tX5/3)).

Comment: This breaks when the attribute value includes `'` or `"` characters. [Regex are not suitable for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)