# PHP Regex remove all attributes except style with regex

Tags: php

Here i remove all attributes from tags:

```
$body = preg_replace('/<(\w+) [^>]+>/', '<$1>', $body); //remove attributes from html
```

How do i amend to exclude style tags?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927816/remove-all-attributes-in-html-tag-except-specified-with-regex

Answer (score 0):

You could add a negative lookahead to the regex pattern which excludes `style` tags:

```php
$body = preg_replace('/<(?!style\b)(\w+) [^>]+>/', '<$1>', $body);
```